# Function only executes when refresh the page, not on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I ran into this strange issue, I hope someone will be able to help.

```
var k_img = jQuery('#'+c['id']).parents('.PhotoCommentImage').children('.PhotoCommentImg');

k_img[0].onload = (function() {

//these statements only executes when refresh the page, not on first load.

});
```

What I am trying to do is to execute statements when an image is finished loading. The strange thing here is that these statements only executes when we load the page. If we refresh the page it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `$(k_img[0]).bind('load', function() { // });`

Comment: `The strange thing here is that these statements only executes when we load the page. If we refresh the page it works fine.` what?

Comment: Is the ID created the first it loads, or it will be created after?

Comment: Do you run your code inside the `$(document).ready()` handler? If not, why not? EVERY jQuery tutorial shows this, I'm sure.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer if you get a chance to accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, please try `$(k_img[0]).bind('load', function() { // });`